# Which PDO SQL Query is faster in the long run and heavy data?

Tags: mysql, pdo, query-optimization

From a Table has over a **million record**, When i pull the data from it,

I want to check if the requested data **exists** or not, So which path is more **efficient** and **faster** then the other?

```
$Query = '
    SELECT n.id 
    FROM names n 
    INNER JOIN ages a ON n.id = a.aid 
    INNER JOIN regions r ON n.id = r.rid 
    WHERE id = :id
';
```

---

```
$stmt->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    ......................
} else {
    exit();
}
```

or

```
$EXISTS = 'SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT n.fname, n.lname, a.age, r.region 
    FROM names n 
    INNER JOIN ages a ON n.id = a.aid 
    INNER JOIN regions r ON n.id = r.rid 
    WHERE id = :id
    LIMIT 1
)
';
$stmt->prepare($EXISTS);
$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);
if ($stmt->fetchColumn() == 1) {
    $stmt->prepare($Query);
    $stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    ......................
} else {
    exit();
}
```

keeping in mind that `id` is `PRIMARY (INT)` and `aid, rid` are `INDEXED (INT)`

Comment: FYI any question asking for help with query optimization should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in your query, so we don't have to guess at your data types, indexes, and constraints. And please post it in text, not as a screenshot like many people do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods you show are almost certainly equivalent, with almost no measurable difference in performance.

```
SELECT n.id 
FROM names n 
INNER JOIN ages a ON n.id = a.aid 
INNER JOIN regions r ON n.id = r.rid 
WHERE id = :id
```

I assume `names.id` is the primary key of that table. A primary key lookup is very fast.

Then it will do a secondary key lookup to the other two tables, and it will be an index-only access because there's no reference to other columns of those tables.

You should learn how to use EXPLAIN to analyze MySQL's optimization plan. This is a skill you should practice any time you want to improve the performance of an SQL query.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

```
mysql> explain SELECT n.id 
    ->     FROM names n 
    ->     INNER JOIN ages a ON n.id = a.aid 
    ->     INNER JOIN regions r ON n.id = r.rid 
    ->     WHERE id = 1;

+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n     | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | ref   | aid           | aid     | 5       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | NULL       | ref   | rid           | rid     | 5       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

We see that each table access is using an index (I'm assuming indexes though you did not provide your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in your question).

Compare to the second solution with `SELECT EXISTS(...)`

```
mysql> explain SELECT EXISTS (
    ->     SELECT n.id 
    ->     FROM names n 
    ->     INNER JOIN ages a ON n.id = a.aid 
    ->     INNER JOIN regions r ON n.id = r.rid 
    ->     WHERE id = 1 
    ->     LIMIT 1);

+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL  | NULL       | NULL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |     NULL | No tables used |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | n     | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index    |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | a     | NULL       | ref   | aid           | aid     | 5       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index    |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | r     | NULL       | ref   | rid           | rid     | 5       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+
```

The subquery looks identical to the first query optimization plan; it still uses indexes in the same way. But it's relegated to a subquery. Probably not a big difference, but it's one more thing.

The only advantage is that the `SELECT EXISTS...` query is guaranteed to return just one row with a true/false value. The first query might return a result set with zero, one, or many rows, depending how many matched the JOINs in the query. The difference is not a performance difference (unless it returns so many rows that it takes time to transfer the result set to the client, or uses a lot of memory to hold the result set in the client), but just a matter of convenience for the way you code it.

Comment: If i removed the `LIMIT 1`, Would that make the `SELECT EXISTS -> SELECT` faster in checking?

Comment: When you get down to micro-optimization, you should just try it both ways and time it with [microtime()](http://php.net/microtime)

Comment: Does indexing the data make the number of records `1 million` obsolete? Since i thought having a 1 million data indexed would still take a lot of time as if it is not indexed? And yes as you predicted, All of the rows are indexed if they're going to be used.

Comment: The point of an index is to make searches avoid reading all million rows. Like if you look up a name in a telephone book, you don't have to read every page, you can find any name in just a few tries. It's still a bit slower as the table grows, but only as a logarithm of the number of rows, not directly proportional to the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't normalize ages; it is just a waste of space and time.  `age` (assuming it is 'years') can fit in a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (range: 0..255) and avoid the `JOIN` lookup.  Note that `aid` seems to be a 4-byte `INT`, which can hold billions of different values -- do you have billions of different ages?

Perhaps changing `regions` is worth it also.

In the first query, the two `JOINs` do nothing but verify that there are rows in age and regions.  That is *probably* a waste.

`EXISTS` stops when one row is found.  So `LIMIT 1` is very unnecessary.