# Which is Faster? Combined or Multiple Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Is there any different between these queries in matter of **Performance** in a table with **`1 million record`**?

`id` IS `PRIMARY`

`userid` IS `INDEXED`

`name` IS `UNIQUE`

**Combined Queries:**

```
$Query = 'SELECT name, (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM reports WHERE userid = 1)) AS status 
FROM users 
WHERE id = 1 
LIMIT 1';

$stmt->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$name = $row['name'];
$status = $row['status'];
```

---

**Multiple Queries:**

## 1

```
$Query = 'SELECT name
FROM users 
WHERE id = 1 
LIMIT 1';

$stmt->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$name = $row['name'];
```

## 2

```
$Query = 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM reports WHERE userid = 1)';
$stmt->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute();
$status = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: This is almost the same question as the one you asked 1 hour ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955316/which-pdo-sql-query-is-faster-in-the-long-run-and-heavy-data but you have learned nothing of what I suggested: use `EXPLAIN`, measure the performance yourself, and at least show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your tables when you post your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second version, MySQL has to compile, parse, and execute two queries.  In the first, only one query has to be compiled, parsed, and executed.

Stop there.  Which do you think is faster?  And by about how much?

As with all performance questions, you can try it out yourself and see which is faster.

The overhead of running such simple queries can be quite important.  If you care about performance, you want an index on `users(id, name)` and on `reports(userid)`.  The first query should then be faster because of the overhead of running queries.

Comment: So lesser is better in this case.

Comment: @Toleo . . . As a general rule, letting the database do as much work as possible is a good idea.  Databases are optimized to handle complex queries.  (There are exceptions, but this is a good default habit.)